# How to create column which is generated automatically in relation to primary key which is the foreign key fro

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, I am creating this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Purchase 
(
     PurchaseID INT NOT NULL 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(ProductID) PRIMARY KEY,
     TotalQuantity INT NOT NULL,
     Price AS (PurchaseID.PRICE), 
     TotalPrice AS (TotalQuantity*Price),
     SalesAssistantID INT NOT NULL 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SalesAssistant(SalesAssistantID), 
     CashierID INT NOT NULL 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cashier(CashierID)
)
```

Above code only represents what I want to achieve (`Price AS (PurchaseID.PRICE)`), `Price` should be created whenever the `PurchaseID` is specified so that `TotalCost` can also function automatically, I could not solve this problem. How to do it?

Comment: I guess, you want to get Price value from Product table, but you can not make it with computed columns. You need to use a trigger for achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for respond, but for my case the trigger is not the solution I want to save TotalPrice at the same table, Purchse in above case, I could not find a solution yet(

Answer (score 0):

```
PurchaseID int identity(1,1) Primary key
```

This makes purchaseID primary key, and `(1,1)` Means it will start at 1 and increment by 1.